# how to check last operation using C

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm making circular queue using C, and the book says there are other ways to check whether queue is full or empty.
One is to make (Rear = (Rear+1) % QueueSize) like this. this is basic way.
The other is to check last operation. If last operation was enqueue, it can't be a empty, and if last operation was dequeue, it can't be a full.
But i have no idea how to check last operation using C

```
int isEmpty_lastOP(QueueType *cQ) {
    if (???) {
        printf(" Circular Queue is empty! ");
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
int isFull_lastOP(QueueType *cQ) {
    if (???) {
        printf("  Circular Queue is full! ");
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
void enQueue_lastOP(QueueType *cQ, element item) {
    if (isFull_lastOP(cQ))  return;
    else {
        cQ->rear = (cQ->rear + 1) % cQ_SIZE;
        cQ->queue[cQ->rear] = item;
    }
}
element deQueue_lastOP(QueueType *cQ) {
    if (isEmpty_lastOP(cQ)) exit(1);
    else {
        cQ->front = (cQ->front + 1) % cQ_SIZE;
        return cQ->queue[cQ->front];
    }
}
```

Comment: you queue is empty if `front==rear`, and full if `front-rear>=cQ_SIZE` also I would recommend applying modulo to front and rear only if front>cQ_SIZE it woudl simplify your code.

Comment: You'd have to store the last operation inside QueueType, for example by adding an enum member with a numeric code for each operation.

Comment: @Ludlin and how will it help to check if the queue is empty or full? It only makes sence if you want to implement  `undo` operation

Comment: Thanks all you guys, i made it!